# this code is supposed to write to a file but doesnt

Tags: java, model-view-controller, file-io

```
public String updateTasks(String oldBean, String catName,String taskname1)
{

File inputFile = new File(catName+".todo");
File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.todo2");

BufferedReader reader1 = null ;//
BufferedWriter writer1 = null;// 

String lineToEdit = taskname1;
String currentLine;



try {
writer1=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
reader1=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
  } 
catch (IOException e) 
            {
e.printStackTrace();
            }


try {
 while((currentLine = reader1.readLine()) != null) {

 String[] sa = currentLine.split(":");
if(sa[0].equals(lineToEdit))
                    {
writer1.write(oldBean+ System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    //continue;
                    }

writer1.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));//this //is supposed to write to a file
```

return Constants.SUCCESS;

```
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("error occurred....");
}

return null;






    }
```

this method is supposed to write to myTempFile.todo1 but wont write 
    anything.
    file is created alright but doesnt write anything.
    since write doesbt return anything theres no way to check.

Comment: Since you're using a `BufferedWriter`, try to use the `flush` method.

Comment: it worked   thank you